# One call function for UIView animation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In my project, I've got 10 of these code here:

```
- (void) makeAnim1{

    //downward animation for carousel
    [UIView animateWithDuration:**3.5**
                          delay:0.25
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         carousel.frame = CGRectOffset(carousel.frame, 0, **490**);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){ //task after an animation ends
                         [self performSelector:@selector(makeAnim1_1) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
                         NSLog(@"Done!");
                     }];    

}

- (void) makeAnim1_1{

    //upward animation for carousel
    [UIView animateWithDuration:**3.5**
                          delay:0.2
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         carousel.frame = CGRectOffset(carousel.frame, 0, **-480**);
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         //timer for the reveal button
                         [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 //this arranges the duration of the scroll
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(revealButton)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:NO];   
                         NSLog(@"Done!");
                     }];    


}
```

I wanted to make them in just one short implementation. So they will be just one function.
I've tried putting the needed values and assigning them in the **bold** version of the code.

I need to have two arrays that corresponds to each other. For example:

arrayA[3] = A,B,C;

arrayB[3] = a,b,c;

When A is pick it is equal to a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code :

You can convert Array Values to Uppercase or lowercase like below code:

A array contains first index is A to convert a
B array contains first index is a

```
if([A objectAtIndex:0] lowercaseString].isEqualString([B objectatindex:0])
{

}
```

Thanks...!